# Issue in Radio Button Action Listener

Tags: java

I have written some code when one of the option in radio button is clicked 
it should display one jlabel and jtext field. And when other option in the radio button is clicked it should  hide the previous shown jlabel and jtext field and display new jlabel and jtext field.

In the output when I click on one of the radio button it is displaying nothing unless and until I maximize my Window. After geting my jlabel and jtextfield If I click on other radio button the jlabel and jtextfield is hidden but Im not able to see new jlabel and jtextfield for that radiobutton.

```
enter code here


public class Emp4 {

    private JFrame frame;
 private JTextField jtxtName;
 private JTextField jtxtAge;
 private JTextField jtxtSal;
  private JTextField jtxtHour_Pay;
    private JTextField jtxtHour_Worked;


     public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Emp4 window = new Emp4();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        });
    }

    public Emp4() {
    initialize();
    }


    private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
    panel.setBounds(30, 11, 414, 36);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblEmployeeDatabase = new JLabel("Employee Database");
    lblEmployeeDatabase.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblEmployeeDatabase.setBounds(157, 7, 193, 25);
    panel.add(lblEmployeeDatabase);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
    panel_1.setBounds(10, 61, 464, 230);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel jlblEmpName = new JLabel("Employee Name");
    jlblEmpName.setBounds(10, 11, 110, 14);
    panel_1.add(jlblEmpName);

    jtxtName = new JTextField();
    jtxtName.setBounds(114, 8, 120, 20);
    panel_1.add(jtxtName);
    jtxtName.setColumns(10);

    JLabel jlblEmpAge = new JLabel("Employee Age");
    jlblEmpAge.setBounds(10, 52, 110, 14);
    panel_1.add(jlblEmpAge);

    jtxtAge = new JTextField();
    jtxtAge.setColumns(10);
    jtxtAge.setBounds(114, 49, 120, 20);
    panel_1.add(jtxtAge);

    JLabel jlblEmpType = new JLabel("Employee Type");
    jlblEmpType.setBounds(10, 95, 110, 14);
    panel_1.add(jlblEmpType);

    JRadioButton jrdbuttonFullTime = new JRadioButton("Full Time");
    JRadioButton jrdbtnContract = new JRadioButton("Contract ");
    JLabel jlblEmpHour = new JLabel("Hourly Rate");
    jlblEmpHour.setBounds(5, 121, 66, 14);
    ButtonGroup group =new ButtonGroup();
    JLabel jlblEmpSal = new JLabel("Salary");
    jlblEmpSal.setBounds(114, 121, 66, 14);
    JLabel jlblEmpWork = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
    jlblEmpWork.setBounds(150, 120, 86, 24);

    jtxtSal = new JTextField();
    jtxtSal.setColumns(10);
    jtxtSal.setBounds(164, 121, 109, 23);

    jtxtHour_Pay = new JTextField();
    jtxtHour_Pay.setColumns(10);
    jtxtHour_Pay.setBounds(75, 121, 59, 23);

    jtxtHour_Worked = new JTextField();
    jtxtHour_Worked.setColumns(10);
    jtxtHour_Worked.setBounds(243, 121, 109, 23);

    group.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);
    group.add(jrdbtnContract);

    jrdbuttonFullTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected()){
                //jrdbtnContract.setSelected(false);

                panel_1.add(jlblEmpSal);
                panel_1.add(jtxtSal);
                jlblEmpHour.setVisible(false);
                jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(false);
                jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(false);
                jlblEmpWork.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    });


    jrdbuttonFullTime.setBounds(113, 91, 109, 23);
    panel_1.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);



    jrdbtnContract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jrdbtnContract.isSelected()){
                //jrdbuttonFullTime.setSelected(false);

                panel_1.add(jlblEmpHour);
                panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Pay);
                panel_1.add(jlblEmpWork);
                panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Worked);
                jlblEmpSal.setVisible(false);
                jtxtSal.setVisible(false);
            }


        }
    });
    jrdbtnContract.setBounds(218, 91, 109, 23);
    panel_1.add(jrdbtnContract);






      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I have understood how it works

Answer (score 1):

Insteed of adding and removing components, simply add all and hide/show them on radiobox selection like this:

```
panel_1.add(jlblEmpSal);
panel_1.add(jtxtSal);

panel_1.add(jlblEmpHour);
panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Pay);
panel_1.add(jlblEmpWork);
panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Worked);

ActionListener myAction = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        jlblEmpHour.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
        jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
        jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
        jlblEmpWork.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());

        jlblEmpSal.setVisible(jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected());
        jtxtSal.setVisible(jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected());

    }

};
myAction.actionPerformed(null); // to initialize labels first
    jrdbuttonFullTime.addActionListener(myAction); // add actionlisteners 
    jrdbtnContract.addActionListener(myAction);// add actionlisteners
```

As you can see, you dont even need 2 separate action listeners as one but shared instance is just enough.
So the complete app will look like this:

```
public class Emp4 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField jtxtName;
    private JTextField jtxtAge;
    private JTextField jtxtSal;
    private JTextField jtxtHour_Pay;
    private JTextField jtxtHour_Worked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Emp4 window = new Emp4();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Emp4() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        panel.setBounds(30, 11, 414, 36);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblEmployeeDatabase = new JLabel("Employee Database");
        lblEmployeeDatabase.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblEmployeeDatabase.setBounds(157, 7, 193, 25);
        panel.add(lblEmployeeDatabase);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 61, 464, 230);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel jlblEmpName = new JLabel("Employee Name");
        jlblEmpName.setBounds(10, 11, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpName);

        jtxtName = new JTextField();
        jtxtName.setBounds(114, 8, 120, 20);
        panel_1.add(jtxtName);
        jtxtName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel jlblEmpAge = new JLabel("Employee Age");
        jlblEmpAge.setBounds(10, 52, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpAge);

        jtxtAge = new JTextField();
        jtxtAge.setColumns(10);
        jtxtAge.setBounds(114, 49, 120, 20);
        panel_1.add(jtxtAge);

        JLabel jlblEmpType = new JLabel("Employee Type");
        jlblEmpType.setBounds(10, 95, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpType);

        JRadioButton jrdbuttonFullTime = new JRadioButton("Full Time");
        JRadioButton jrdbtnContract = new JRadioButton("Contract ");
        JLabel jlblEmpHour = new JLabel("Hourly Rate");
        jlblEmpHour.setBounds(5, 121, 66, 14);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        JLabel jlblEmpSal = new JLabel("Salary");
        jlblEmpSal.setBounds(114, 121, 66, 14);
        JLabel jlblEmpWork = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
        jlblEmpWork.setBounds(150, 120, 86, 24);

        jtxtSal = new JTextField();
        jtxtSal.setColumns(10);
        jtxtSal.setBounds(164, 121, 109, 23);

        jtxtHour_Pay = new JTextField();
        jtxtHour_Pay.setColumns(10);
        jtxtHour_Pay.setBounds(75, 121, 59, 23);

        jtxtHour_Worked = new JTextField();
        jtxtHour_Worked.setColumns(10);
        jtxtHour_Worked.setBounds(243, 121, 109, 23);

        group.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);
        group.add(jrdbtnContract);

        panel_1.add(jlblEmpSal);
        panel_1.add(jtxtSal);

        panel_1.add(jlblEmpHour);
        panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Pay);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpWork);
        panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Worked);

        ActionListener myAction = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                jlblEmpHour.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
                jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
                jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());
                jlblEmpWork.setVisible(jrdbtnContract.isSelected());

                jlblEmpSal.setVisible(jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected());
                jtxtSal.setVisible(jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected());

            }

        };
        myAction.actionPerformed(null); // to initialize labels first
        jrdbuttonFullTime.addActionListener(myAction);
        jrdbtnContract.addActionListener(myAction);

        jrdbtnContract.setBounds(218, 91, 109, 23);
        jrdbuttonFullTime.setBounds(113, 91, 109, 23);
        panel_1.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);
        panel_1.add(jrdbtnContract);

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. Now I got to know how it really works

Answer (score 1):

I've revised your code a little.  This should get you going on the right path:

```
public class Emp4 {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField jtxtName;
    private JTextField jtxtAge;
    private JTextField jtxtSal;
    private JTextField jtxtHour_Pay;
    private JTextField jtxtHour_Worked;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Emp4 window = new Emp4();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Emp4()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        panel.setBounds(30, 11, 414, 36);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblEmployeeDatabase = new JLabel("Employee Database");
        lblEmployeeDatabase.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblEmployeeDatabase.setBounds(157, 7, 193, 25);
        panel.add(lblEmployeeDatabase);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        panel_1.setBounds(10, 61, 464, 230);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel jlblEmpName = new JLabel("Employee Name");
        jlblEmpName.setBounds(10, 11, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpName);

        jtxtName = new JTextField();
        jtxtName.setBounds(114, 8, 120, 20);
        panel_1.add(jtxtName);
        jtxtName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel jlblEmpAge = new JLabel("Employee Age");
        jlblEmpAge.setBounds(10, 52, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpAge);

        jtxtAge = new JTextField();
        jtxtAge.setColumns(10);
        jtxtAge.setBounds(114, 49, 120, 20);
        panel_1.add(jtxtAge);

        JLabel jlblEmpType = new JLabel("Employee Type");
        jlblEmpType.setBounds(10, 95, 110, 14);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpType);

        JRadioButton jrdbuttonFullTime = new JRadioButton("Full Time");
        JRadioButton jrdbtnContract = new JRadioButton("Contract ");
        JLabel jlblEmpHour = new JLabel("Hourly Rate");
        jlblEmpHour.setBounds(5, 121, 66, 14);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        JLabel jlblEmpSal = new JLabel("Salary");
        jlblEmpSal.setBounds(114, 121, 66, 14);
        JLabel jlblEmpWork = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
        jlblEmpWork.setBounds(150, 120, 86, 24);

        jtxtSal = new JTextField();
        jtxtSal.setColumns(10);
        jtxtSal.setBounds(164, 121, 109, 23);

        jtxtHour_Pay = new JTextField();
        jtxtHour_Pay.setColumns(10);
        jtxtHour_Pay.setBounds(75, 121, 59, 23);

        jtxtHour_Worked = new JTextField();
        jtxtHour_Worked.setColumns(10);
        jtxtHour_Worked.setBounds(243, 121, 109, 23);

        //*******************************************************************
        // Add all your salary fields here, not in ActionListeners
        // Start them off invisible
        //*******************************************************************
        jlblEmpSal.setVisible(false);
        panel_1.add(jlblEmpSal);

        jtxtSal.setVisible(false);
        panel_1.add(jtxtSal);

        panel_1.add(jlblEmpHour);
        jlblEmpHour.setVisible(false);

        panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Pay);
        jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(false);

        panel_1.add(jlblEmpWork);
        jlblEmpWork.setVisible(false);

        jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(false);
        panel_1.add(jtxtHour_Worked);

        group.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);
        group.add(jrdbtnContract);

        jrdbuttonFullTime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (jrdbuttonFullTime.isSelected()) {
                    //jrdbtnContract.setSelected(false);

                    // ****************************************************
                    // In ActionListeners for radiobuttons, hide the fields you
                    // don't want to see, make visible the ones you do want to see
                    // ****************************************************
                    jlblEmpSal.setVisible(true);
                    jtxtSal.setVisible(true);
                    jlblEmpHour.setVisible(false);
                    jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(false);
                    jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(false);
                    jlblEmpWork.setVisible(false);
                }

            }
        });

        jrdbuttonFullTime.setBounds(113, 91, 109, 23);
        panel_1.add(jrdbuttonFullTime);

        jrdbtnContract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (jrdbtnContract.isSelected()) {
                    //jrdbuttonFullTime.setSelected(false);

                    // ****************************************************
                    // In ActionListeners for radiobuttons, hide the fields you
                    // don't want to see, make visible the ones you do want to see
                    // ****************************************************
                    jlblEmpHour.setVisible(true);
                    jtxtHour_Pay.setVisible(true);
                    jlblEmpWork.setVisible(true);
                    jtxtHour_Worked.setVisible(true);
                    jlblEmpSal.setVisible(false);
                    jtxtSal.setVisible(false);
                }

            }
        });
        jrdbtnContract.setBounds(218, 91, 109, 23);
        panel_1.add(jrdbtnContract);

    }
}
```

Your radio buttons start off both unchecked, so you see no salary detail initially.  When you click one or the other, the corresponding details appear.

Answer (score 0):

In which case(which radiobutton checked ?) you want to show which controls?